# In R data.table, how to standardize test set with mean and standard deviation of the training set

Tags: r, data.table

I came across R data.table and was very impressed by its power. I am trying to apply what I learned from Python/Scikit learn. More specifically, I try to standardize a test set with the mean and standard deviation of the training set.

```
# my training set
my_dt <- as.data.table(data.frame(list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5))))
# my testing set
my_dt2 <- as.data.table(data.frame(list(a=c(4,5,6), b=c(7,8,9))))

cols <- colnames(my_dt)

# I calculate the column means and standard deviation
my_dt_colmean <- my_dt[,lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols=cols]
my_dt_colsd <- my_dt[,lapply(.SD, sd), .SDcols=cols]

# How to apply to the testing set. I tried to use the following but it is not correct.
my_dt2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - my_dt_colmean[x])/my_dt_colsd[x]), .SDcols=cols]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can make use of `Map`

```
my_dt2[, Map(f1, .SD, my_dt_colmean, my_dt_colsd), .SDcols = cols]
#   a b
#1: 2 3
#2: 3 4
#3: 4 5
```

where `f1` is

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z) (x - y)/z
```